# Using colorcet when plotting xarray scatter plot

Tags: seaborn, scatter-plot, python-xarray

I am trying to assign 31 different colors using the package colorcet on xarray, but when assigning the pallete to the cmap, the resulting plot does not receives the command and it only repeats the same colors over and over along the 31 different hues.

```
import seaborn as sns
import colorcet as cc

palette = sns.color_palette(cc.glasbey, n_colors=31)
ds2.plot.scatter(x="salinity", y="temperature", hue="latitude",marker='.',linewidth=0,  add_guide= True, cmap= palette, levels =31,hue_style='discrete')
plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
```

When I plot dataframes using the palette command: palette = palette, I get the desired results, but this time I am working with xarrays and the syntax is a little different from what I am used to.
Is there a way I can get the different 31 colors in my scatter plot using colorcet?

Comment: There is no direct way to use a custom colormap with xarray scatter plots. However, you can convert your xarray data to a pandas DataFrame and then use seaborn or matplotlib for a more customizable scatter plot.

Comment: That's good to know! Converting to DataFrame did the trick :)

Comment: glad i could help, goodluck!

Answer (score 0):

`colorcet` seems to represent its palettes as a list of strings with hexadecimal color values.  You can subset that list and create a `ListedColormap`.  But note that more than about 12 colors are extremely hard to distinguish visually.

```py
import colorcet as cc
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

cmap = ListedColormap(cc.glasbey[:31])
ds2.plot.scatter(x="salinity", y="temperature", hue="latitude", marker='.', linewidth=0, add_guide=True, 
                 cmap=cmap, levels=31, hue_style='discrete')
```